# How to un-mininize NSWindow programmatically ?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I am a newer one for MACOS development. I have created an instance of NSWindowController.

Is it possible to show (un-minimize) the window when the NSWindow is minimized by user ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with

```
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

**UPDATE**:

There is a function especially to deminiaturize a window but the effect is the same.

```
window.deminiaturize(self)
```

Comment: @Willeke: I updated my answer but no matter what you use, the effect is the same.

Comment: @Willeke Did you try `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`? Because it does in fact deminiaturize. Also, `deminiaturize:` has the effect of making the window key and frontmost even on non-miniaturized windows. There is no apparent difference (in the user experience) between the two methods.